# Codeigniter use third party class

Tags: php, codeigniter, namespaces

So I want to use third party library form my project. This library calls "blockchainApi" and is stored in `application/third_party/` dir.

[image: directory]

so in my model I just use:

```
require_once APPPATH . '/third_party/blockchainApi/Blockchain.php';
$Blockchain = new \Blockchain\Blockchain(PAYMENTS_BTC_API_CODE);
```

and its load normal, but when I try to reach method from this class, it returns me error, method:

```
$response = $Blockchain->Receive->generate($data['wallet'], $data['callback_url']);
```

error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Blockchain\Create\Create' not found in <..>blockchainApi/Blockchain.php on line 65

so the problem is:

[image: problem]

this not working... so how to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use composer autoloader?

Comment: i don't know how to use it with codeigniter

Answer (score 3):

I believe this guide is the best thing for you. And you will have a chance to use composer.

https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2012/05/composer-with-codeigniter/

This is happening due to [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standards and not having an autoloader for namespaces

**Edit:**

From what I see here [(link)](https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-php#getting-started) you will probably need composer.

It is preferable to find a machine with linux. On terminal move to an empty folder run the following command:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Then you will have inside your folder a composer.phar file.

After that you create a composer.json file and inside you write:

```
{
        "name": "project",
        "description": "",
        "license": "MIT",
        "authors"
        "require": {
            "php" : ">=5.3.0",
            "blockchain/blockchain" : "1.*"
        },
        "require-dev": {

        }
}
```

Then run

```
composer.phar update
```

Then upload inside you project folder

```
- vendor (folder)
- composer.lock
- composer.json
```

Inside you index.php include the autoloader

```
include_once './vendor/autoload.php'
```

Optionally to run composer from everywhere by simply typing composer copy composer.phar to your local bin

```
cp composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Then instead of composer.phar you can do:

```
composer update
```

Comment: the project is hosted on shared hosting without SSH access. Is it possible to install composer in shared host?

Comment: You might need then to do you own implemantation http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/

Comment: @ArnasPečelis - there's nothing that says you need to run composer on the host.  You can just as easily install your libraries locally, then upload the entire vendor folder to your web host.

Comment: Hey, It's seems that working composer with codeigniter. But I can't load blockchain library. It gives me no error, I can load other libraries using composer, but not the blockchain. Any ideas? It only gives me `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: This can be absolutely anything.